# GCS: Access denied - service not available in your location

Tags: google-cloud-storage

since some days ago we are getting an "Access forbidden" error when trying to download any resources uploaded to Google Cloud Storage from some of our servers.

That resources are shared publicly and they are available from all the other locations we've tested.

For example, this is URL https://migoa.storage.googleapis.com/static/r45001/images/cancel.png should be accessible world-wide. We tested it and it's working. But, when trying to download it from one of our servers, instead of the image, we got this XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access denied.</Message>
<Details>We're sorry, but this service is not available in your location</Details>
</Error>

[javi@OK ~]$ lwp-request https://migoa.storage.googleapis.com/static/r45001/images/cancel.png -dS
GET https://migoa.storage.googleapis.com/static/r45001/images/cancel.png --> 200 OK

[javi@notOK ~]$ lwp-request https://migoa.storage.googleapis.com/static/r45001/images/cancel.png -dS
GET https://migoa.storage.googleapis.com/static/r45001/images/cancel.png --> 403 Forbidden
```

Adding the host "migoa.storage.googleapis.com" to the server hosts file, pointing to another location IP (Google Cloud Storage acts as CDN using the best per-location server), the image is downloaded without problems, so, it seems a problem with the resolved Google server, in our case, this:

```
dig +short migoa.storage.googleapis.com
storage-ugc.l.googleusercontent.com.
74.125.136.132
```

In fact, we don't know how many locations can be affected. Also, we've been using GCS from almost 1 year without any problems until now.

Any idea about how to solve this?

Regards,

Comment: Where is your server located?

Comment: Amsterdam, The Netherlands. But we have more servers at the same location working fine. All depends on the resolved IP at the DNS level...

Comment: Could you send the output of `gsutil perfdiag gs://bucketname` to gs-team@google.com from one of the servers with the problem?